# Magento 1 - Add Tier Price Column in Catalog > Manage Products Grid

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-group, tierprice, product-grid

I want to add a now column in Catalog > Manage Products Grid with a specific Tier Price for a customer group.
Is there any chance i can add that?
Thank you!